# Will threading improve the speed of this loop?

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading

I am looping through a bunch of pickle files, doing some calculations and sorting, and then saving the pickle to the same file. It takes about 15ms per iteration, and 180 iterations total. If I tried threading this instead of looping through it, would that mean the entire thing is done in 15ms?

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

files = os.listdir('folder')

for f in files:
   df = pd.read_pickle('folder/'+f)
   df = df.sort_values(by='time')
   df = df.iloc[-100:,:]
   df.to_pickle('folder/'+f)
```

now before you just say try it and test the speed - I don't know how to do threading and it will take me a bit to learn so I thought I would just ask instead. I am working on a desktop pc with a intl i3-8109U, which I think has 4 processors? Not sure if that matters.

Comment: multiprocessing would be more appropriate as it's mainly CPU intensive. But you could try both with ThreadPoolExecutor and ProcessPoolExecutor as the api is interchangeable between the two and therefore easy to test the performance

Comment: No.  I expect that the iteration time will be dominated by file reading and writing.  Those are slow operations and essentially serial.  But you should probably time each line of the code to get some data, you may find my educated guess to be wrong.

Comment: Yes, it matters how many CPUs you have, provided it's CPU-bound. Also, it matters how many harddisks you have and how the read/write operations are distributed, if and when it's IO-bound. Also, it matters how things overlap when you parallelize things. Interesting, complex topic, but worth learning!

Comment: The read write take about 0.02 seconds of the 0.15 seconds total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you could do this using multiprocessing. If you want to try multithreading just import ThreadPoolExecutor and use that instead of ProcessPoolExecutor. No other code changes would be needed.

```
import pandas as pd
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from glob import glob
import time

def do_work(file):
   df = pd.read_pickle(file)
   df = df.sort_values(by='time')
   df = df.iloc[-100:,:]
   df.to_pickle(file)

def main():
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(do_work, glob('folder/*'))
    end_time = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Duration={end_time-start_time:2f} seconds')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I think that's too fast. Are you sure that *do_work()* was ever called? I suspect you may have the wrong path as the argument to *glob()*. Add *print('Running')* as the first line in *do_work()* to be certain

Comment: I've checked the outputs they seem to all be good.